# Android Studio :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac package R does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, java-8, retrolambda

I hava setted up a App project with retrolambda for JAVA 8 compatibility and a module dependency to a own android library, because I used this part in a second App too.
The problem is that every time I build my Project with gradle there is no error and the build success, but when I want to install the App on my Device, gradle fails in

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac with package R does not exist
```

Here is my gradle setup:

*build.gradle (Project: "Projectname")*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*build.gradle (Module: app)*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'org.florescu.android.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.3.0'
    compile project(path: ':myownmodule')
}
```

*build.gradle (Module: myownmodule)*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    configurations {
        compile.exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.3'
}
```

This is the output from gradle console:

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :myownmodule:generateDebugSources, :myownmodule:mockableAndroidJar, :myownmodule:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :myownmodule:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :myownmodule:compileDebugSources, :myownmodule:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :myownmodule:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
Jack is required to support java 8 language features.
Jack is required to support java 8 language features.
:clean
:app:clean
:myownmodule:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:myownmodule:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:myownmodule:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:myownmodule:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:myownmodule:compileLint
:myownmodule:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:myownmodule:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:myownmodule:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:myownmodule:checkReleaseManifest
:myownmodule:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:myownmodule:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:myownmodule:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:myownmodule:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:myownmodule:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Library
:myownmodule:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Library
:myownmodule:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library
:myownmodule:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Library
:myownmodule:prepareIoReactivexRxandroid110Library
:myownmodule:prepareReleaseDependencies
:myownmodule:compileReleaseRenderscript
:myownmodule:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:myownmodule:generateReleaseResources
:myownmodule:packageReleaseResources
:myownmodule:compileReleaseAidl
:myownmodule:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:myownmodule:mergeReleaseShaders
:myownmodule:compileReleaseShaders
:myownmodule:generateReleaseAssets
:myownmodule:mergeReleaseAssets
:myownmodule:mergeReleaseResources
:myownmodule:processReleaseManifest
:myownmodule:processReleaseResources
:myownmodule:generateReleaseSources
:myownmodule:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:myownmodule:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:myownmodule:compileRetrolambdaRelease
:myownmodule:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:myownmodule:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:myownmodule:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:myownmodule:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:myownmodule:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:myownmodule:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:myownmodule:bundleRelease
:app:prepareProjectnameBalldbmodelUnspecifiedLibrary
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42400Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2400Library
:app:prepareIoReactivexRxandroid110Library
:app:prepareOrgFlorescuAndroidRangeseekbarRangeseekbarLibrary030Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/path/to/project/Projectname/app/src/main/java/my/package/app/adapter/HersListAdapter.java:37: error: package R does not exist
        View layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_hers, parent, false);
                                                                        ^
/path/to/project/Projectname/app/src/main/java/my/package/app/adapter/HersListAdapter.java:56: error: package R does not exist
                ListActivity.switchTo(listActivity, str(R.string.series)+" " + hers.getName(), hers);
                                                                             ^
/path/to/project/Projectname/app/src/main/java/my/package/app/adapter/HersListAdapter.java:80: error: package R does not exist
            root = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.root);
                                                       ^
/path/to/project/Projectname/app/src/main/java/my/package/app/adapter/HersListAdapter.java:82: error: package R does not exist
            hersImg = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.hersImg);
                                                             ^
/path/to/project/Projectname/app/src/main/java/my/package/app/adapter/HersListAdapter.java:84: error: package R does not exist
            hersname = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.hersname);
                                                             ^
/path/to/project/Projectname/app/src/main/java/my/package/app/adapter/HersListAdapter.java:85: error: package R does not exist
            ballanzahl = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.count);
                                                         ^
/path/to/project/Projectname/app/src/main/java/my/package/app/adapter/PassListAdapter.java:35: error: package R does not exist
        View layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_two_lines, parent, false);
                                                                        ^
/path/to/project/Projectname/app/src/main/java/my/package/app/adapter/PassListAdapter.java:61: error: package R does not exist
            root = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.root);
                                                       ^
/path/to/project/Projectname/app/src/main/java/my/package/app/adapter/PassListAdapter.java:63: error: package R does not exist
            line1 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.line1);
                                                    ^
/path/to/project/Projectname/app/src/main/java/my/package/app/adapter/PassListAdapter.java:64: error: package R does not exist
            line2 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.line2);
                                                    ^
/path/to/project/Projectname/app/src/main/java/my/package/app/adapter/PisteListAdapter.java:35: error: package R does not exist
        View layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_two_lines, parent, false);
                                                                        ^
/path/to/project/Projectname/app/src/main/java/my/package/app/adapter/PisteListAdapter.java:65: error: package R does not exist
            root = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.root);
                                                       ^
/path/to/project/Projectname/app/src/main/java/my/package/app/adapter/PisteListAdapter.java:67: error: package R does not exist
            line1 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.line1);
                                                    ^
/path/to/project/Projectname/app/src/main/java/my/package/app/adapter/PisteListAdapter.java:68: error: package R does not exist
            line2 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.line2);
                                                    ^
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
14 errors

 FAILED
:app:compileRetrolambdaDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileRetrolambdaDebug'.
> Process 'command '/path/to/jdk_1.8.0-72_x86_64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
==============================================================================

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 32.407 secs
```

I'm wondering about this, because my second app with the same setup can be installed without any problem.
Why gradle crashs in this app? In my java classes there is while programming no problem and the import to the android R class exists, but while build for installing gradle removed this import and all R's will be red till a few seconds. Android Studio auto import the right R

```
import my.package.app.R;
```

and after the import the R's are not red anymore.

I have tested a gradle clean and rebuild several times (as suggested in other questions) without fixing the problem...

Thanks for helping :D

Comment: Did you ever get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had a recent project that was working fine until today occur with the same error.

Error: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources > 1

I tried all the usual fixes, restarting, resyncing, clean solution, invalidate cache and restart. Nothing worked until...

The Fix:

For each of your build.gradle files in each class, you will seem something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ac130.memorygame"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

Now, open up a new project. This new project should debug just fine. Copy and paste the new project build.gradle from Gradle Scripts and replace the old/broken project's build.grade file with that code. Change the application ID to what was on your old project. Save and Resync with Gradle. You will now be able to use your app!.